# Set default value option with Angular ReactiveForm setValue method

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to set default value of select option with Angular 7, but it doesnt set default option value;

Here what I tried to do.

At the component  I am using `setValue()` method to set default value.

```
this.courseForm.controls['selectedTeacher'].setValue(this.course['Teacher'],{onlySelf: true});
```

And at the template I am using select like this:

```
  <select formControlName="selectedTeacher">
      <option *ngFor="let teacher of teachers" [ngValue]="teacher">
                    {{ teacher.FirstName }} {{teacher.LastName}}
       </option>
 </select>
```

Normally when try like this with input text it works but select list doesnt work.

I couldn't realize exactly what the problem is.

Help please,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses objects reference, instead of properties, so if you do this, it will work if you have unique identifier for each teacher

```
const teacher = this.teachers.find(t=> t.id == this.course['Teacher'].id);
this.courseForm.controls['selectedTeacher'].setValue(teacher,{onlySelf: true});
```

Or you can find by any unique property

```
const teacher = this.teachers.find(t=> t.FirstName == this.course['Teacher'].FirstName && t.LastName == this.course['Teacher'].LastName  );
```

Answer (score 0):

change in your component:

```
this.courseForm.controls['selectedTeacher'].setValue(this.course['Teacher'].id,{onlySelf: true})
```

in your html:

```
<select formControlName="selectedTeacher">
      <option *ngFor="let teacher of teachers" [value]="teacher.id">
                    {{ teacher.FirstName }} {{teacher.LastName}}
       </option>
 </select>
```